# Logstash S3 output prefix - event date field value

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, elk

How to set Logstash S3 output prefix dynamically with an event field value in format: "%{+YYYY}/%{+MM}/%{+dd}/%{+HH}" ?

```
input:
{"record_time":"2017-03-09T04:07:51.520Z"}

required s3 prefix: 
2017/03/09/04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grok to match `record_time` to extract year, month, day, hour and then mutate into `s3 prefix`:

```
grok {
  match => {
    "record_time" => "%{INT:year}-%{INT:month}-%{INT:day}T%{INT:hour}:%{GREEDYDATA}"
  }
}

mutate {
  # Create s3 prefix
  add_field => {
    "s3_prefix" => "%{year}/%{month}/%{day}/%{hour}"
  }

  # If you don't need separate values, remove them
  remove_field => ["year", "month", "day", "hour"]
}
```

Comment: NUMBER not recognizing 03. Changing grok pattern to: "%{INT:year}-%{INT:month}-%{INT:day}T%{INT:hour}:%{GREEDYDATA}" worked. Tq!

Comment: didn't think of that, thank you for the correction. I'll update the answer